# cursor: none; doesn't always work on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, cursor, mouse

Using `cursor: none;` dynamicaly (with javascript) isn't working consistently on Chrome. This works just fine on opera or firefox. The css actually changes, but the cursor is not hidden! YouTube also uses this logic, with same result.

```
var mouseTimeout;
document.body.onload = function () {
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    $('.building').addEventListener('mousemove', cursorHandler);

}

function cursorHandler() {
    console.log('cursorHandler');
    document.querySelector('.building').style.cursor = 'default';
    console.log('show curser');
    if (mouseTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(mouseTimeout);
    }
    mouseTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('hide curser');
        document.querySelector('.building').style.cursor = 'none';
    }, 3000);
}
```

Anyone know a good workaround for this problem?

Comment: Apparently this is a Chrome bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723 not sure what the solution could be though, I'll try to find a workaround.

Comment: well trying to add transparent png image may be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but when I have Chrome Developer tools open it is not consistent. As soon as I close it, everything works as expected.
I'm using a transparent .gif file as cursor.
Cheers!